# Find and replace text inside several notepads stored in a folder

Tags: vbscript

We have a folder inside which we have 1000 notepads which has data. We are trying to find and replace user defined strings in all of those notepads without opening them individually.Can you help me with a vb script functions which asks from the user which string he wants to replace and what should that be replaced with and then replace those in all the notepads simultaneously.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate files in VBScript? Do you know how to open and read an existing text file? What kind of script have you managed to put together on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Const TristateFalse = 0 ' ASCII
Const TristateTrue = -1 ' Unicode
Const TristateUseDefault = -2 ' System Default

Dim sFindExpr, sReplaceWith, sFolder, oFile, sContent

sFolder = "C:\Test\files"
sFindExpr = InputBox("Enter expression to be replaced")
sReplaceWith = InputBox("Enter expression to replace with")

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each oFile In .GetFolder(sFolder).Files
        With .OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, 1, False, TristateUseDefault)
            sContent = ""
            If Not .AtEndOfStream Then sContent = .ReadAll
            .Close
        End With
        sContent = Replace(sContent, sFindExpr, sReplaceWith)
        With .OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, 2, False, TristateUseDefault)
            .Write(sContent)
            .Close
        End With
    Next
End With

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "Completed", 1, , 64
```